# How to select last occurrence of duplicating record in oracle

Tags: database, oracle

I am having a problem with Oracle query where the basic goal is to get the last row of every re-occurring rows, but there's a complication that you'll understand from the data:

Suppose I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID    | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | UPDATED_DATE
------|------|------|------|-------------
001   | a    | b    | c    | 14/05/2013
002   | a    | b    | c    | 16/05/2013
003   | a    | b    | c    | 12/05/2013
```

You should be able to guess that since columns 1 to 3 have the same values for all 3 rows they are re-occurring data. The problem is, I want to get the latest updated row, which means row #2.

I have an existing query that works if the table is without ID column, but I still need that column, so if anybody could help me point out what I'm doing wrong, that'd be great.

```
select col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       max(updated_date)
  from tbl
 order by col1, col2, col3;
```

The above query returns me row #2, which is correct, but I still need the ID.

Note: I know that I could have encapsulate the above query with another query that selects the ID column based on the 4 columns, but since I'm dealing with millions of records, the re-query will make the app very ineffective.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
WITH qry AS 
(
  SELECT ID, COL1, COL2, COL3, updated_date, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL1, COL2, COL3 ORDER BY updated_date DESC) rank
  FROM tbl
)
SELECT ID, COL1, COL2, COL3, updated_date
  FROM qry
 WHERE rank = 1
```

or

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.COL1, t2.COL2, t2.COL3, t2.updated_date
  FROM tbl t1 JOIN
(
  SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, MAX(updated_date) updated_date
    FROM tbl
   GROUP BY COL1, COL2, COL3
) t2 ON t1.COL1 = t2.COL1
    AND t1.COL2 = t2.COL2
    AND t1.COL3 = t2.COL3
    AND t1.updated_date = t2.updated_date
```

Output in both cases:

```
| ID | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |               UPDATED_DATE |
--------------------------------------------------------
|  2 |    a |    b |    c | May, 16 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/68e5c/5)** demo for both queries.

Comment: thank you! it works perfectly! i need to learn about analytic query, i guess.